# jQuery how can I pause the function?

Tags: jquery, performance, function, pausing-execution

Ok, I'm new to jQuery and not an expert. Here is the first part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

...and the second one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var $win = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ($win < $("#portfolio").offset().top - 50 || $win >= $("#referencje").offset().top - 50) {
            window.menuup = '#404040';
            window.menuover = '#FFFFFF';
            window.socialup = '#00577F';
            window.socialover = '#80D7FF';
            $(".colleft, .boxemptyDesk, .boxcontainerleft").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#000000"}, 1000);
            $(".colright, .boxcontainerright").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#1A1A1A"}, 1000);
            $(".menu p").stop().animate({"color": "#202020"}, 1000);  
            $(".menu p a").stop().animate({"color": "#404040"}, 1000);  
            $(".social p, .social p a").stop().animate({"color": "#00577F"}, 1000);  
            $(".flydark").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);  
            $(".boxbiggray, .boxgray, .pboxbiggray").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#262626"}, 1000);
            $(".subtitle").stop().animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"}, 1000);  
        }
        else if ($win >= $("#portfolio").offset().top - 50 && $win < $("#referencje").offset().top - 50) {
            window.menuup = '#BFBFBF';
            window.menuover = '#000000';
            window.socialup = '#80D7FF';
            window.socialover = '#00577F';
            $(".colleft, .boxemptyDesk, .boxcontainerleft").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 1000);
            $(".colright, .boxcontainerright").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2"}, 1000);
            $(".menu p").stop().animate({"color": "#DEDEDE"}, 1000);  
            $(".menu p a").stop().animate({"color": "#BFBFBF"}, 1000);  
            $(".social p, .social p a").stop().animate({"color": "#80D7FF"}, 1000);  
            $(".flydark").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000);  
            $(".boxbiggray, .boxgray, .pboxbiggray").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9"}, 1000);
            $(".subtitle").stop().animate({"color": "#000000"}, 1000);  
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, that I have to pause the second part of this code, while the first part is executing. And I don't have any idea, how to do it... Oh, I have to pause this code, because both in the same time works very slowly and the animation isn't smooth. Someone could help?

Comment: wrap both parts into 2 separate functions; 
execute second function as a callback in the `animate` call.

Comment: JS doesn't do two things "at the same time" (async stuff notwithstanding)

Comment: Can't you call the second function in the first?

Comment: I'm not sure understand you question right :)
But if you want to attach different action to windows and .scroll 
You shold add .not() function to $(window) 
like this:
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).not('.scroll').scroll(function () {

Comment: @Alnitak actually it does: when you click the button the body is scrolling and with every pixel the second part is executed which might cause the lags

Comment: you can give the second function as a callback to the animate in first function. $.animate gives an option to pass a function to be called after animation is complete [link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: @tborychowski well, the animations do rely on async timer events.  The problem here seems to be an over-active scroll event handler that shouldn't always be invoked.  Perhaps a flag?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, that seems to be the real problem here. But if it's executed in callback after animation is completed (and not in every step of the scroll) it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you might try is to use the 'complete' callback: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

complete
Type: Function()
A function to call once the animation is complete.

So instead of having 2 instances of $(document).ready(...) you'd have only one, and your first bit of code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 2000, function(){
        $(window).scroll(function () {
    var $win = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ($win < $("#portfolio").offset().top - 50 || $win >= $("#referencje").offset().top - 50) {
        window.menuup = '#404040';
        window.menuover = '#FFFFFF';
        window.socialup = '#00577F';
        window.socialover = '#80D7FF';
        $(".colleft, .boxemptyDesk, .boxcontainerleft").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#000000"}, 1000);
        $(".colright, .boxcontainerright").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#1A1A1A"}, 1000);
        $(".menu p").stop().animate({"color": "#202020"}, 1000);  
        $(".menu p a").stop().animate({"color": "#404040"}, 1000);  
        $(".social p, .social p a").stop().animate({"color": "#00577F"}, 1000);  
        $(".flydark").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);  
        $(".boxbiggray, .boxgray, .pboxbiggray").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#262626"}, 1000);
        $(".subtitle").stop().animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"}, 1000);  
    }
    else if ($win >= $("#portfolio").offset().top - 50 && $win < $("#referencje").offset().top - 50) {
        window.menuup = '#BFBFBF';
        window.menuover = '#000000';
        window.socialup = '#80D7FF';
        window.socialover = '#00577F';
        $(".colleft, .boxemptyDesk, .boxcontainerleft").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 1000);
        $(".colright, .boxcontainerright").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2"}, 1000);
        $(".menu p").stop().animate({"color": "#DEDEDE"}, 1000);  
        $(".menu p a").stop().animate({"color": "#BFBFBF"}, 1000);  
        $(".social p, .social p a").stop().animate({"color": "#80D7FF"}, 1000);  
        $(".flydark").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000);  
        $(".boxbiggray, .boxgray, .pboxbiggray").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9"}, 1000);
        $(".subtitle").stop().animate({"color": "#000000"}, 1000);  
    }
});
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Sorry, but your script doesn't work. Effect is exactly the same, as with my script. One more thing. The second part of my script changes colors on the page, and it has to work all time, because you can scroll page manually, then colors must be changed. So i have to pause the second part of my script for a while, not execute by a click.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've got the solution! Here's the link: http://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Pause works great, and do exactly what I want. First looping function pauses, when the second starts and when it's done, first function starts again and loop. And here's correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        $.fn.pause = function(n) {
            return this.queue(function() {
                var el = this;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    return $(el).dequeue();
                }, n);
            });
        };

        $(window).queue(function switchColor() {
            var $win = $(window).scrollTop();
            if ($win < $("#portfolio").offset().top - 50 || $win >= $("#referencje").offset().top - 50) {
                window.menuup = '#404040';
                window.menuover = '#FFFFFF';
                window.socialup = '#00577F';
                window.socialover = '#80D7FF';
                $(".colleft, .boxemptyDesk, .boxcontainerleft").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#000000"}, 1000);
                $(".colright, .boxcontainerright").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#1A1A1A"}, 1000);
                $(".menu p").stop().animate({"color": "#202020"}, 1000);  
                $(".menu p a").stop().animate({"color": "#404040"}, 1000);  
                $(".social p, .social p a").stop().animate({"color": "#00577F"}, 1000);  
                $(".flydark").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1000);  
                $(".boxbiggray, .boxgray, .pboxbiggray").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#262626"}, 1000);
                $(".subtitle").stop().animate({"color": "#FFFFFF"}, 1000);  
            }
            else if ($win >= $("#portfolio").offset().top - 50 && $win < $("#referencje").offset().top - 50) {
                window.menuup = '#BFBFBF';
                window.menuover = '#000000';
                window.socialup = '#80D7FF';
                window.socialover = '#00577F';
                $(".colleft, .boxemptyDesk, .boxcontainerleft").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 1000);
                $(".colright, .boxcontainerright").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#F2F2F2"}, 1000);
                $(".menu p").stop().animate({"color": "#DEDEDE"}, 1000);  
                $(".menu p a").stop().animate({"color": "#BFBFBF"}, 1000);  
                $(".social p, .social p a").stop().animate({"color": "#80D7FF"}, 1000);  
                $(".flydark").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000);  
                $(".boxbiggray, .boxgray, .pboxbiggray").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9"}, 1000);
                $(".subtitle").stop().animate({"color": "#000000"}, 1000);  
            }
            $(this).clearQueue();
        });
    });

    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $(window).pause(2000);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```